# ¿Como hacer una copia de una matriz en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

```
    while(True):

    tabla_aux = tabla
    tabla = gravedad(tabla)

    if tabla == tabla_aux:
        break
```

Quiero hacer una copia de la tabla en aux, para despues llamar a una funcion (gravedad) que hace cambios, pero que si no hace ningun cambio se salga del bucle.

El problema es que aun estando así, tabla_aux se actualiza a la vez que tabla.
A ser posible debería ser sin utilizar ninguna librería, pero si no queda otra me sirve.

Answer (score 0):

Dando por hecho que es una matriz construida con numpy (teniendo en cuenta el problema que te está dando), la solución pasa por utilizar el método `copy` de esa librería:

```
while(True):

    tabla_aux = np.copy(tabla)
    tabla = gravedad(tabla)

    if tabla == tabla_aux:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Te está pasando porque `tabla` y `tabla_aux` son el mismo objeto en memoria.
Si pones:

```
if tabla == tabla_aux:
    print(tabla is tabla_aux)
```

Verás que te devuelve `True`

Prueba con:

```
from copy import copy
tabla_aux = copy(tabla)
```